# what is the difference from using ionic capacitor and npx cap

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have different problems in ionic framework from using `npx cap` or `ionic capacitor`? I was wondering what the difference was?
I might have the camera work with using `npx cap` but it wont work with `ionic capacitor`
I will run code with the ionic framework and needing to know the differences and the commands I should use ? or is it based on my situation?
I am developing with the latest Canary build for android and latest angular framework. I am new to the ionic framework but not js or angular

Comment: any insight on this?